# How use Windows Alt+Tab feature to handle Chrome tabs as a separate standalone window?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11, taskbar

I am using Chrome in Windows 11.

When I use the Windows feature Alt+Tab to switch between windows, then it regards Chrome with multiple tabs just one window. I would like to regard Chrome tabs as separate items.

Example:

I have opened App1, App2 and Chrome with Tab1 and Tab2, then I would like to iterate over those *four* and not just App1, App2 and "The Chrome".

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can, unless you switch to Microsoft Edge:

> Windows 10 can now show your Microsoft Edge browser tabs as separate
> entries with thumbnails in the Alt+Tab switcher. **You'll have to use
> Microsoft Edge if you want browser tabs in your Alt+Tab switcher. As
> of October 2020, this doesn't work in Google Chrome or Mozilla
> Firefox.**

Taken from: https://www.howtogeek.com/696939/how-to-show-all-your-browser-tabs-in-alttab-on-windows-10/